# CSS not working properly after deploying Sencha Application to Android device

Tags: android, css, sencha-touch

I am creating a Sencha Touch Application. I am using css gradients for background. Now when I test on the browser it is working perfect. But as soon as I deploy it on my android device, it is not working as expected.

I am attaching my code and the screenshots of the applications when it is tested on a desktop browser and when it is deployed on mobile.

Here is my sencha code:

```
  xtype: 'panel',
  style:"background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,right top,right top,color-stop(0.09, #FF00FF),color-stop(0.7, #99FF99),color-stop(1, #993366));background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right top, #FF00FF 9%, #99FF99 70%, #993366 100%);background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right top, #FF00FF 9%, #99FF99 70%, #993366 100%);background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right top, #FF00FF 9%, #99FF99 70%, #993366 100%);background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right top, #FF00FF 9%, #99FF99 70%, #993366 100%);background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #FF00FF 9%, #99FF99 70%, #993366 100%)",

  styleHtmlContent: true,
  scrollable: true,
  width:'100%',
  height:'100%',
```

When I test in on my browser the screen looks like this:

[image]

But as soon as I deploy it on my mobile, then screen looks like this:

[image]

I can't understand why the whole css disappears while deploying sencha application to android. Any help in this case is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The support for older Android gradients has gone missiong in Sencha Touch 2.3.

For me the following has fixed it:

From your `_gradients.scss (/resources/themes/vendor/compass-recipes/stylesheets/receipes/background/)` remove `Line 36 ($support-for-original-webkit-gradients: false;)`

Afterwards rebuild css with compass. :-)